# Let $K$ a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$. Show that $\mathbb{Q} \subset K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$. Show that $\mathbb{Q} \subset K$.

To do this, I am trying to use an exercise done in class : Let $K$ a field, $\alpha \in K$ and $L$ a subfield of $K$. Then $L(\alpha)$ is the smallest subfield of $K$ containing $L$ and $\alpha$.

Is anyone could give me a hint to solve this problem?

Comment: Here's why we only consider $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ as finite field extensions in $\mathbb C$, I've never noticed this detail! Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By definition of a subfield, $K$ contains $0$ and $1$ and all finite sums of its elements and all negatives of its elements and all quotients (not by $0$) of its elements.

Comment: +1, nice answer. More generally, any subfield of a field $K$ contains the prime subfield of $K$, i.e. the smallest subfield of $K$ containing $1_{K}$.